# Include login name in post C#

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner at C# and I'm trying to do a simple task. I'm doing a very simple message board, you login through a DB and make a post to a .txt file. I want to do a post, that include the username that you are logged in with, but I can't get it to work. I'm trying to pull the username out of the DB and include it in my post, but its just a blank field.

Its running on a local server. This is my connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Myconnection" connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-5J21T5R;Initial Catalog=Login;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

The login process works just fine and below is the part where I want to post a comment and include the login username. I've been googling it for several hours now and every post I come across tells to connect to the DB and do that string UserName, but nothing happens when I use the UserName string in the post. I have tried the Environment.UserName, but that just returns the user on my pc and not the logged in username.

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //Tildel filsti og filnavn
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:/Opslagstavle/besked.txt", true);

        //Skriv en besked + database indlæs til brugernavn
        string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Myconnection"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(mainconn);
        string UserName = connectionStringBuilder.UserID;

        sw.WriteLine("Skrevet af: " + UserName);
        sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime());
        sw.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text);

        //Luk StreamWrite objekt
        sw.Close();
    }
    finally
    {
    }
}
```

I'm writing the message in a textbox and extracting the previous messages in a listbox.

This is the login string:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (Session["TxtUsername"] != null)
    {
        LabUsrname.Text = Session["TxtUsername"].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
}
```

Sorry if this is too confusing, but I need to find out how to do a post, that includes the username of the user that is logged in. Is this even doable?

Comment: What do you mean with the **login name**? You mean the name of the database user? You have no user id (`null`) because you are using windows authentication. Do you mean to get the username of the windows account?

Comment: I mean the username of the database user, like i use a username to access the message board. I want to include that username in the post.

Comment: Ooof, you're learning C# and you started with a WebForms project?

Comment: No, i haven't started with this, its just where im at right now :) Im doing an assignment and i can't figure out what im doing wrong.

Comment: Still didn't understood what you mean by login name. What authentication method are you using?

Comment: You are using windows authentication to login to your database (the `Integrated Security=True` part), not a **user** and **pw**. That's why `UserID` returns null.

Comment: I see, what does it have to look like to extract the username ?

Comment: [Here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) are examples of connection strings. For logging in with username/pw you need the first one on the page.

Comment: Aha, thank you for your time and your answer, i appreciate it.

Comment: To be precise, these aren't answers - they're comments. It's an important distinction in terms of how the site is intended to run/be used

Comment: Yes, i will see if i can answer my own question with the new information, then i will post a solution if possible.

Comment: @dhb82 I posted it as an answer, hope it is acceptable

Comment: Very good, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Integrated Security=True` part indicates that you are using Windows Authentication to login to your database, instead of using Sql Authentication (with `username/pw`).
For this reason, `connectionStringBuilder.UserID;` returns `null`.

If you wish to get the name of the current Windows User: `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`

For SQL Authentication your connection string should be like this:
`Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;`
This way you will get the value `UserID`.

You can find more connection string examples [here.](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)

Comment: Clarify `username/pw` as only relating to SQL Authentication. To switch username in Windows Auth you need to `Impersonate()`